# "Open an existing file in Spreadsheetgear using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to open an existing file in `WorkBookView` (named `wkbMain` in code given below) placed on my Windows Form. I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub MenuItemOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lObjDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    wkbMain.GetLock()

    Try
        If lObjDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            wkbMain = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(lObjDialog.FileName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        wkbMain.ReleaseLock()
    End Try
End Sub
```

But the assignment

```
wkbMain = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(lObjDialog.FileName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`)
```

throws an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'ᢷ' to type 'SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView'.

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the WorkbookView.[ActiveWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~ActiveWorkbook.html) property to the object returned by Factory.GetWorkbook(...), not on your WorkbookView object itself.  Example:

```
wkbMain.ActiveWorkbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(lObjDialog.FileName, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim Andersen.
Looks like you are a good helping hand for me in Spreadsheetgear programming. Also I am going to finish my tasks with your kind help. Once again thanks a lot for your kind help.